# File name encoding in Python 2.7

Tags: python, character-encoding

I want to read files with special file names in Python (2.7). But whatever I try, it always fails to open them.
The filenames are

```
F\xA8\xB9hrerschein
```

and

```
Gro\xDFhandel
```

I know, the encoding was done with one of several codepages. I could try to find out which one and try to convert it and all the mumbo jumbo, but I don't want that.

Can't I somehow tell python to open that file without having to go through all that encoding stuff? I mean opening the file by its raw name in bytes?

Comment: Why don't you want to name them like "Fuehrerschein" or "Grosshandel"?

Comment: @palsch not everything maps to ASCII, and assuming so is culturally insensitive. People should be able to name their files in their preferred language, and programs should be able to deal with that.

Comment: @amon right, but in this case...

Comment: ...it's not the answer, but maybe helping in *this* case.

Comment: @fr00tyl00p have you tried looking in the list os.listdir list, what the filename looks like for python?

Comment: @palsch Renaming is not an option. os.listdir gives ['Gro\xdfhandel', 'F\xa8\xb9hrerschein']

Comment: Please provide some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all, I fixed it with

```
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

and setting the environment variable

```
LANG="C.UTF-8"
```

Thanks for the hints.

Comment: Downvote for use of `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')`. This is a nasty hack, which will mask further issues. Having the correct LANG will go along way to help Python, which depends upon a healthy locale.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `os.listdir()`. See the following example.

Add some data to a file with non-ascii character 0xdf in the name:

```
$ echo abcd > `printf "A\xdfA"`
```

Check that the file contains a non-ascii character:

```
$ ls A*
A?A
```

Start Python, read the directory and open the first file (which is the one with the non-ascii character):

```
$ Python
>>> import os
>>> d = os.listdir('.')
>>> d
['A\xdfA']
>>> f = open(d[0])
>>> f.readline()
'abcd\n'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have source code like

```
with open('Großhandel') as input:
    #stuff
```

You should look at [Source Code Encodings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) and write

```
 #!python2
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 with open('Großhandel') as input:
 …
```

It is worth mention that the authors of PEP-263 are Marc-André Lemburg and Martin von Löwis, which I suppose makes pushing defined toward source encoding back in 2002 slightly more understandable.

Comment: The file name comes from the filesystem. It's not written in the code.

Comment: So show us the code you have and what is failing, otherwise your question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux, filenames can be encoded in any character encoding. When opening a file, you must use the exact name encoded to match.

I.e. If the filename is `Großhandel.txt` encoded using UTF-8, it must be encoded as `Gro\xc3\x9fhandel.txt`.

If you pass a Unicode string to `open()`, the user's locale is used to encode the filename, which may match the filename.

Under OS X, UTF-8 encoding is enforced. Under Windows, the character encoding is abstracted by the i/o drivers. A Unicode object passed to `open()` should always be used for these Operating Systems, where it'll be converted appropriately.

If you're reading filenames from the filesystem, it would be useful to get decoded Unicode filenames to pass straight to `open()` - Well, you can pass Unicode strings to `os.listdir()`.

E.g.

Locale: `LANG=en_GB.UTF-8`

A directory with the following files, with their filenames encoded to UTF-8:

```
test.txt
€.txt
```

When running Python 2.7 using a string:

```
>>> os.listdir(".")
['\xe2\x82\xac.txt', 'test.txt']
```

Using a Unicode path:

```
>>> os.listdir(u".")
[u'\u20ac.txt', u'test.txt']
```